# BING MAPS Windows Store Pushpin MapView

Tags: bing-maps, windows-store-apps

I have a Map on my Windows Store app that adds multiple pushpins.

Is there any way to have the map control "MapVew/ZoomLevel" automatically adjust to always zoom to a level where all the pushpins are visible?

Thanks in advance.

/Eric

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty easy to do:

1. [Get a LocationRect from your list of Pushpin coordinates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846491.aspx)
2. [Call SetView on your map and pass it the LocationRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846504.aspx)
3. Redo step 1 & 2 each time your collection of visible Pushpins change.

Comment: Thanks. This looked promising but it's not quite right. It just centers the map in the middle of the pins but doesn't adjust the zoom to fit them all in the screen.

Comment: Then you are either not using the API correctly or Bing Maps has bug, because here is what it says in the API reference:  
"SetView( LocationRect rect)
Sets the map view using the specified geographical region."  If you specified your rect to correctly encompass all the Pushpin locations, then the map should adjust its center location and zoom level to make that area appear on screen.